# DX12 Games Crash, DDU in Safe Mode, OS reinstalled, BIOS updated Still no fix

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, crash, directx

PC Specs:

- Ryzen 5 5600x
- 16gb Trident Z Neo @ 3600mhz
- B550 Aorus Pro AC Wireless (Bios Version 13h)
- EVGA - SUPER XC ULTRA GAMING NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Super 8GB GDDR6
- 700w EVGA PSU

I've been trying to get DX12 games to run for a few weeks now, sometimes they work the majority of time they crash to the desktop. The games I've been trying are RDR2, Control, Horizon Zero Dawn, Spyro the Dragon. All of them crash but other intense games run without issue, such as the Witcher 3, Far Cry 5 or GTA V. I've done a clean windows install within the last week, I've DDU removed my gpu drivers and installed new ones through their website. I've run memory diagnostic which came back without any issue, the RAM I've got is validated on AMD's website I've got no answers. RDR2 generates errors when it crashes in event viewer, SOTR created them once.

The description for Event ID 13 from source nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

```
\Device\Video3 Graphics Exception: MISSING_INLINE_DATA
\Device\Video3 Graphics Exception: MISSING_MACRO_DATA
\Device\Video3 Graphics Exception: ESR 0x404600=0x80000002
Faulting application name: RDR2.exe, version: 1.0.1355.23, time stamp: 0x601ddf87 
Faulting module name: RDR2.exe, version: 1.0.1355.23, time stamp: 0x601ddf87 Exception code: 0x80000003 
Fault offset: 0x0000000002582f34 
Faulting process id: 0x3b3c 
Faulting application start time: 0x01d722161ccb9a15 
Faulting application path: C:\EpicGames\Games\RedDeadRedemption2\RDR2.exe Faulting module path: C:\EpicGames\Games\RedDeadRedemption2\RDR2.exe 
Report Id: b0ddf541-425a-4a33-8ed5-e988c310bcba 
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

For SOTR tn, had these errors which look similar to RDR2. But I ran Cyberpunk for 20 minutes, no crash I just got tired and decided to head to bed
The description for Event ID 13 from source nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

\Device\Video3
Graphics Exception:  MISSING_MACRO_DATA

The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table
The description for Event ID 13 from source nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

```
\Device\Video3
Graphics Exception: ESR 0x404490=0x80000001

The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table
Faulting application name: SOTTR.exe, version: 1.0.298.0, time stamp: 0x5eba7467
Faulting module name: SOTTR.exe, version: 1.0.298.0, time stamp: 0x5eba7467
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000006f9ae26
Faulting process id: 0x4144
Faulting application start time: 0x01d72c4df042459e
Faulting application path: D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Shadow of the Tomb Raider\SOTTR.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Shadow of the Tomb Raider\SOTTR.exe
Report Id: 7c0f696a-f7b3-4777-9d14-520e743157fc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Driver install failed, result=0x80004004 for devnode 'PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1E84&SUBSYS_31733842&REV_A1\4&2283F625&0&0019'
Driver install failed, result=0x80004004 for devnode 'PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1AD9&SUBSYS_31733842&REV_A1\4&2283F625&0&0319'
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*
Update, I changed out the Ram kit as a joke and all my issues are resolved, RMA-ing the old one. Updating all my posts so anyone who has an issue can get a step in the right direction!